# How to get back menu bar in Kile after switching to LXDE?

Tags: menu, lxde, kile

I switched from Gnome/Unity to LXDE on my netbook because it has only 1 GB RAM. Now the Kile window has no menu bar. How does one get it back?

This does not affect all KDE applications - for example, Kate does have a menu bar.

Comment: do you have a file & folder called `.kde/share/config/kilerc` - what happens if you rename this file i.e. to reset kile's settings?

Comment: Yes, renaming this file (resetting settings) brings back the menu bar. I'd like a way to do this without modifying other settings, though.

Comment: ok... it sounds like a corruption in the file itself - I think its a text file so you should be able to compare your old file with your newly regenerated file to see what the issue is.  I think it would be useful if you can pastebin.com both your existing kilerc file and a newly regenerated file to compare with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `~/.kde/share/config/kilerc`, look for the section `[KileMainWindow]`, and within that look for the line `menubar=Disabled`. Change `Disabled` to `Enabled` or delete this line.

Thanks to @fossfreedom for suggesting looking in `~/.kde/share/config/kilerc`.

Comment: thanks I add the same issue for a long time but using ubuntu+gnome-shell, this fixed it :)

Answer (score 4):

<sub>converted comment to answer</sub>

A similar issue was reported on [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11485384).

In this case it was reported against Kubuntu - so the observation that you have switched to LXDE perhaps is not the key issue here.

The resolution was to rename the file `~/.kde/share/config/kilerc`.

This file will then be regenerated when you next start Kile.

This will result in your own customisation settings being lost but user-defined shortcuts are retained.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to destroy your settings:

- Open the file `~/.kde/share/config/kilerc` with an editor.
- Look for `[KileMainWindow]`.
- Change the setting `MenuBar=Disabled` to `MenuBar=Enabled`.

Answer (score 0):

The location of `kilerc` on my PC is `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/kilerc`. As mentioned in the other answers, go to this file and change `menubar=Disabled` to `menubar=Enabled`.